# Capture word text as html

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am working on MS Word application capturing tool in which we capture selected contents  via some keystrokes. All things done. 
Now in selected range i would like to capture text as html for example

Text = **Hello There. How** are *you* ?

I have done above query by below code sample

```
string str = string.Empty;
Word.Range rngFindBold =
    ((Word.DocumentClass)(wh.Document)).ActiveWindow.Selection.Range;
rngFindBold.Find.Font.Bold = -1;
foreach (Word.Range rngWord in rngFindBold.Words)
{
    if (rngWord.Bold != 0)
    {
        // rngWord.Bold = 0;
        //rngWord.Text = "<b>" + rngWord.Text + "</b>";
        str += "<b>" + rngWord.Text + "</b>";
    }
    else if (rngWord.Italic != 0)
    {
        // rngWord.Italic = 0;
        //  rngWord.Text = "<i>" + rngWord.Text + "</i>";
        str += "<i>" + rngWord.Text + "</i>";
    }
    else if (rngWord.Underline != 0)
    {
        //  rngWord.Underline = 0;
        //  rngWord.Text = "<u>" + rngWord.Text + "</u>";
        str += "<u>" + rngWord.Text + "</u>";
    }
    else
    {
        str += rngWord.Text;
    }
}
```

Result = `Hello &lt;b&gt;There&lt;/b&gt;&lt;b&gt;. &lt;/b&gt;&lt;b&gt;How &lt;/b&gt;are &lt;i&gt;you &lt;/i&gt;&lt;i&gt;?&lt;/i&gt;`

Above code takes more time when selecting multiline content

How can i optimize above code?

Comment: Is it just _my_ browser encoding or did Yuck's editing really crash the sample output?

Comment: BTW, the sample input text has 'Hello' in bold, the sample output string does not. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `+=` use a `StringBuilder` object. This handles string operations **much more efficient**.

That would change your code into :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Word.Range rngFindBold =
((Word.DocumentClass)(wh.Document)).ActiveWindow.Selection.Range;
rngFindBold.Find.Font.Bold = -1;
foreach (Word.Range rngWord in rngFindBold.Words)
{
    if (rngWord.Bold != 0)
    {
        builder.Append("<b>" + rngWord.Text + "</b>");
    }
    else if (rngWord.Italic != 0)
    {
        builder.Append("<i>" + rngWord.Text + "</i>");
    }
    else if (rngWord.Underline != 0)
    {
        builder.Append("<u>" + rngWord.Text + "</u>");
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Append(rngWord.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one regular tip: use StringBuilder instead of concatination via add (+) operation.

Anyway performance of COM Interop is slow so bear with it.